# Calling zend form on everypage of my application

Tags: zend-framework

I have a form which I should call in every page, I am using zend framework 1.11. My view helper is like this

```
class Zend_View_Helper_RequestForm 
{
    function requestForm()
    {
        $requestForm = new Application_Form_Request();
        return $this->view->requestForm;

    }
}
```

my application.ini has this

```
resources.view.helperPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"
resources.view[] =
```

In my layout I have

```
echo $this->requestForm();
```

Now I am getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'RequestForm' was not found in the registry;
```

Please help me how do I call the form in every page ? Thanks

Comment: `/views/helpers` is the defined default. Why muck with it? Your error is about how you are using your helper, not where it's at. Your error is faulting a plugin. I'm guessing your trying to use this helper in your bootstrap or something similar. Post that code.

Answer (score 0):

Loading issues like this usually hinge on getting the class naming in sync with the appnamespace and the file location:

1. I would name your helper with the appnamespace (probably defined as `Application` in your `application/configs/application.ini`), so the class name is `Application_View_Helper_RequestForm`. [Better to keep out of the `Zend_` namespace anyway] And as @b.b3rn4rd noted, a good idea to extend `Zend_View_Helper_Abstract`.
2. Place this class in the file `application/views/helpers/RequestForm.php`
3. Call in your view-scripts using `$this->requestForm()`

Comment: Problem is when calling in layout, not in views

Comment: The layout is an example of a view-script, so the calling convention is the same. Fundamentally, the issue is how the view object figures out waht you mean when you invoke `$this->requestForm()`. The resource autoloaders and the view-helper path/prefix mappings tell the sytemm how to resolve the invocation name into a real class to instantiate and a method to call.